# For i in list: -> accessing and using i to index into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

So I have 2 datasets: 1. an array of data (call it x), 2. a pandas dataframe with n columns

I am trying to write a for loop, which goes through each column in my `dataframe` and calculates the correlation coefficient from that column against my first array of data, x.

```
x = [1.2, 1.9, 2.2, 4.1]
y = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'col2': [10, 20, 30, 40]}
example_df = pd.DataFrame(data = y)
for i in example_df.columns:
 print(np.corrcoef(x, example_df.i)[0, 1])
```

However, I am receiving an error

> "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'i'"

I am wondering if anyone has a suggestion for how to access and use `'i'` to access columns in my `dataframe`.

Comment: You need to use `df[i]` if `i` is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
example_df.i
```

… that's asking for a column literally named `i`. And of course you don't have one.

What you have a column named `col1`, and `i` is a variable holding the string `'col1'`. To ask for that, do this:

```
example_df[i]
```

Comment: greatly appreciated, this helped tons ! cheers